# Why does PHP require an explicit reference to "$this" to call member functions?

Tags: php, oop

That's pretty much it.  Scoping in most OO programming languages resolves symbols fine without an explicit reference to the current instance (i.e. '$this' in PHP).  Why does PHP require me to precede every call to a member function in the same class with $this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the point of having $this and self:: in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345408/what-is-the-point-of-having-this-and-self-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To resolve the scope of the function call. Consider:

```
$this->strstr(...
```

and just

```
strstr(...
```

The latter will call PHP's built-in strstr() function which is not what we want to do here.

It's a consequence of adding OOP features to a high level procedural/scripting language.

Comment: Makes sense.  I feel that it's unnecessarily verbose to have to use $this->myFunc() all the time.  However, in the case of PHP's built-in functions, you've got a point.  If the '$this' qualifier weren't required, there would have to be a symbol that explicitly meant 'call the built-in method' (e.g. something like '$->ststr()').  Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Although it would have been perfectly possible to have the function/method call resolved like e.g. C++ does. ::strstr()