# How to call a method of a class?

Tags: php, oop

I got 2x public functions in a class that must call 1 private function with different parameters also in the same class... for some reason it tell me that it can't find the function...

example:

```
class Foo {    

private function Do(...)     
{
       ....
       return $whatever;
}

public function One(...)    
{
  return Do(...);
}

public function Two(...)    
{ 
       return Do(...);
}
```

}

am getting error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function do() in ...

Answer (score 34):

You have to use `$this` to refer to the instance and the [`T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) to access/mutate/call members/methods of an instance, e.g.

```
$this->do();
```

Please go through the

- [Chapter on Classes and Objects in the PHP Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and
- [What is the point of having $this and self:: in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345408)