# How to retrieve Object array value?

Tags: php, arrays, object

The thing is that I'm new to OOP PHP and I seem can't find the answer to how to retrieve a specific value from array of objects.

When I run request to the User class and method find_by_sql:

```
$getAct = User::find_by_sql($sql);
```

The response I get is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => User Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [permissions] => 0
            [email] => email@example.com
            [password] => 918f358a5cdf01e63d4609063d9A2bfec57f8455
            [first_name] => Name
            [last_name] => Surname
            [city] => City
            [gender] => m
            [birth_date] => 1980-02-02
            [act_code] => AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        )

)
```

My question basically is how can I set [act_code] value to my variable?
If I would use the non-static method it would be easy since I could just call $obj->act_code.
But how do I do same from a static method call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do

```
$getAct  = User::find_by_sql($sql);
$actCode = $getAct[0]->act_code;
```

or more verbose

```
$getAct  = User::find_by_sql($sql); // returns an array
$user    = $getAct[0];              // assign first element in array to $user
$actCode = $user->act_code;         // read act_code member from User Object
```

As you can see by your result dump, `$getAct` contains an Array with one element (as indicated by `[0]` [because Arrays are indexed with zero-based keys](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)). The element is a User [Object](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

You [access/mutate/call Object members/methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055709/call-private-function-in-same-class/4055730#4055730) with the `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` (`->`). Since `$getAct[0]` will return a handle to the object, you can then fetch the property by `->get_act`.

Comment: Thanks for answer very in detail. As i'm new i'm not quite aware of all stuff around OOP :)

Answer (score 0):

To assign the value of the first array element's member variable `act_code` to a variable:

```
$act_code = $getAct[0]->act_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what ORM you are using, but if you want to retrieve only one record, just limit it to 1. That should return a User object instead of an array of User objects

```
$user = User::find_first_by_sql($sql);
$act  = $user->act_code;`
```