# Is 'this' required when calling local method inside a class?

Tags: php, class, callback

When I call a local method from my class as shown in the example below, do I have to put `$this->` before it?

Example:

```
class test{
    public function hello(){
        $this->testing(); // This is what I am using
        testing(); // Does this work?
    }
    private function testing(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

The reason why I ask is because I am using the array_map function with a predefined PHP function in it and I am now going to use a function defined by me. This is what I mean:

```
class test{
    public function hello(){
        array_map('nl2br',$array); // Using predefined PHP function
        array_map('mynl2br',$array); // My custom function defined within this class
    }
    private function mynl2br(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just test if it works?

Comment: Just wondering: Why didn't you just try if it works? As far as I know, i won't work. You will have to supply `array_map(array($this, 'mynl2br'), $array);`. See [the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php) for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701509/is-this-required-when-calling-local-method-inside-a-class, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050598/why-does-php-require-an-explicit-reference-to-this-to-call-member-functions

Comment: I didnt test it because I actually wanted a technical explanation of whether or not it would work in order to allow myself and other to understand it better

Comment: Don't know why people voted down as this is an important question!

Comment: @pät Thank you, Nor me!! Probably because they thought I was lazy for not testing it myself. I am not in a position at the moment where I can test it myself, I just thought of it and wanted to know the answer

Comment: @BenCarey If you're in a position to type a testcase here, I assume you could type it in this [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) or this [other codepad](http://codepad.org/) too. If you test it first using such a tool, it shows research effort and the question will be clearer.

Comment: @Ben It's a good question and I've upvoted but you might word it better as it does make you sound a little lazy! Asking "why doesn't this work" or "how can I make this work" will probably get a better response.

Comment: @AnotherCode I wasnt aware of these sites so I apologise, in future, I will head there first. Although this would have answered my question, I wouldn't have learned the information in the answers that have been provided so in this case it turned out to be better for me as I learned something I did not already know. But, thank you

Comment: @BenCarey That's completely right, and in no way I meant to say that you shouldn't have asked or that it was unacceptable to ask without testing it first; just explaining why it was downvoted and giving some hints for future questions. This site is meant for learning :)

Comment: I also just checked this question as i use a free hosting and thats difficult to debug so i just wondered if its really necessary (so far i have to use $this keyword). The quetion is whether is really needed, not whether it works, if im right. hyped replies are unnecessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is required. `testing()` refers to the global function by that name, and will cause an error if the function doesn't exist.

You can, however, make a "callback" with the `$this` variable. As you can see from [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback), you need to make an array where the first element is the object and the second element is the method name.  So here you could do this:

```
array_map(array($this, 'mynl2br'), $array);
```

Comment: I had no idea you could pass a callback as an array!! This is exactly the answer I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Test it yourself :P

The result is that the `testing();` doesn't get triggered but `$this->testing();` does.
`testing();` only refers to functions outside of a class.

```
<?php
class test{
    public function hello(){
        $this->testing(); // This is what I am using
        testing(); // Does this work?
    }
    private function testing(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

function testing() {
    echo 'hi';
}

$test = new test();
$test->hello(); // Output: hellohi
?>
```

See [@lonesomeday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9701584/1157493) for a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: @lonesomeday Me neither but that's all I knew. Your answer is obviously the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a class’ method as a callback, you need to pass an *array* containing the object instance and the method name instead of *just* the method name:

```
array_map(array($this, 'mynl2br'), $array);
```

Instead of

```
array_map('nl2br', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use Closures:

```
array_map(function($el) { ...; return $result; }, $array);
```

Comment: Again, I wasnt aware you could use these sorts of callbacks in PHP. I had only ever used it in javascript! Thanks for the info

Comment: Closures are php => 5.3.0